# Restoring Firefox Session in Selenium

Tags: python, session, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am currently automating a website and have a test which checks the functionality of the Remember Me option.
My test script logs in, entering a valid username and password and checks the Remember Me checkbox before clicking Log In button.

To test this functionality I save the cookies to file using pickle, close the browser and then reopen the browser (loading the cookies file).

```
def closeWebsite(self, saveCookies=False):
    if saveCookies:
        pickle.dump(self.driver.get_cookies(), open('cookies.pkl', 'wb'))
    self.driver.close()

def openWebsite(self, loadCookies=False):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['browserName'] = 'firefox'
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(firefoxProfile)
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    self.driver.get(appUrl)
    if loadCookies:
        for cookie in pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb')):
            self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

However, when I do this, the new browser is not logged in. I understand that everytime you call the open the browser a new Session is created and this session ID can be obtained using `driver.session_id`
Is it possible, in the openWebsite method to load a driver and specify the sessionID? 
When I test this manually, the Remember Me option works as expected. I'm just having trouble understanding how Selenium handles this case.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you're loading the page **before** adding the cookies. Although there is *the potential* for them to arrive before the page needs / queries them, this isn't correct let alone reliable.

Yet, if you try to set the cookies before any page has loaded you [will get an error](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#add-cookie).

The solution seems to be [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#cookies):

> First of all, you need to be on the domain that the cookie will be valid for.  If you are trying to preset cookies before you start interacting with
>   a site and your homepage is large / takes a while to load an
>   alternative is to find a smaller page on the site, [...]

In other words:

1. Navigate to your home page, or a small entry page on the same **domain** as `appUrl` (no need to wait until fully loaded).
2. Add your cookies.
3. Load `appUrl`. From then on you should be fine.

Comment: I haven't managed to get it working yet. I attempted to load a smaller page but my cookies don't seem to be remembered. So I'm unable to complete a valid test of Rememer Me option.

Comment: Did you try creating them *before* navigating to `appUrl`, but after first requesting an entry page (so the browser can add them for your domain)?

Comment: When you say requesting an entry page, do you mean any page on the website that will load quickly, e.g. a 404 page?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @p_cos have you solved this one? I'm having similar troubles trying to set the cookies.